# Angular : How to open Details Component and pass id on ButtonClick

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

I have List and Details components in an Angular (v7) project and I open the Details of a record using the following approach:

***ListComponent.html:***

```
<a routerLink="/details/" [state]="{ id: row.Id }">{{ row.Title }}</a>
```

***DetailsComponent.ts:***

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class DetailsComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router,
        public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute {
        super();

        this.id = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.id; //get id parameter
    }
}
```

I have encountered 2 issues to be fixed:

1) I need to stay on the same Details page on page refresh.

2) I want to open Details page for a record using a button click e.g. appending id parameter to the address of the Details page.

Is it possible to fix these 2 issues in a smart way in Angular 7?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the `id` as a router parameter in the url. And make a new route in your `routing-module` that corresponds with the detail component.

You can see this [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-3-heroes-feature) in the official documentation where they implement a list/detail view with routing.

Basically it would be like this

```
<a routerLink="/details/{{row.Id}}">{{ row.Title }}</a>
```

and

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class DetailsComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router,
        public route: ActivatedRoute) {
        super();

        this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); //get id parameter
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. First of all I use the button in email message and I think I should use href instead of routerLink. On the other hand there is an error on the id line because there is no snapshot property in this.route or this.router. Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the email message. For the snpashot property, I made a mistake in the injection. I changed ` public activatedroute: ActivatedRoute` to ` public route: ActivatedRoute`. The `snapshot` property is a member of `ActivatedRoute`.

Comment: Thşis approach seem to work, BUT when refreshing Details page, **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found** error encountered even if the address is the same as when opening Details page first (.../detail/216). Any idea?

Comment: You are probably using the new `PathLocationStrategy` but haven't configured your webserver to handle this correctly. You can read more about that [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)

Comment: Thanks for your helps, voted up. I solved the problem and post the fix on **[Cannot navigate same route in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559158/cannot-navigate-same-route-in-angular/56563350#56563350)**. Regards...