# Cannot navigate same route in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have a List and Details component in my Angular 7 project and I can open the details of a record by clicking the link on the List page. However, if I refresh on the same Details page or open the same Details page via hyperlink (e.g. opening the same record on the List in a new tab), **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found** is encountered. My code is as shown below:

***routing.module.ts:***

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'user',    
        component: UserPanelComponent

        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: UserDashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'issue/detail/:id',
                component: IssueDetailComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

***list.component.html:***

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/issue/detail/', row.Id]">{{ row.Title }</a>
```

***details.component.ts:***

```
export class DetailComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router,
        public route: ActivatedRoute) {
        super();

        this.id = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.id; //get id
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        /* I also try to use the following method in order to get id value. Both works, 
        but when refrehing page the code does not hit constructor or ngOninit blocks  */

        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); //get id

        this.loadDetails();
    }

    loadDetails() {
        if (this.id) {
            // load details
        }
    }
}
```

The stange thing is that when I click a record on the List component, the id parameter is passed and corresponding record is opened on the Details page. But when I right click on the same record and open it in a new tab OR refresh the page on Details page, **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found** error is encountered. I have tried to apply many suggestions bıt none of them worked. Any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: The component doesn't get re-built if you change the url, and `ngOnInit` doesn't get re-executed. Use an Observable in place of `snapshot`. This is well documented in the official docs

Comment: @CristianTraìna I also tried it as **let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');** AND **this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => { let id = +params.get('id'); })** but nothing was changed. Could you pls post an example? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @CristianTraìna On the other hand if I refresh on the same page, does it men to change the url? Because I think it means to request the same url with the same id parameter. Is not it?

Comment: `let id`? You should change the component state, not just assign a variable. `Observable`s are asyncrhonous. So use `this.id`, but if you don't know how observables or async work, I advise you to deepen these arguments before diving in Anguar

Comment: You should also understand the difference between client side navigation and server side navigation. No answer is so complete to explain all your doubts :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna I used this.id, I just gave an example. On the other hand if you post an example to fix this issue I would understand many things and ask you if there is a point that I do not understand :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna I simply perform 2 things: Getting the same details when refreshing details page and opening details of a record via link e.g. posting the url on address bar. Is it too difficult?

Comment: @Willys maybe this is about your server where app is hosted? https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: @Buczkowski Actually I have test it on localhost (debug) and use the relative localhost in urls. But when details page is working, it does not work on refresh on the same environment. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this behaviour in both local and production environment ?

If you have a HTTP404 maybe it's not linked to angular. I had the same thing when packaging an angular app inside a WAR or JAR with spring boot for executing on an application server. If you do, (and if I remenber well) I had to add this configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").resourceChain(true).addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {

            @Override
            protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't think it will change something, but you can also try this to get the ID :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log("this is my id:"+params['id']);
    });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I just tested on local environment and have not fixed it yet.  Actually I use C# (ASP.NET MVC) rather than Java and it might be better to fix the issue on Angular side. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If the component is opened using a button, hyperlink (e.g. /user/issue/detail?id=100) or the same page should be loaded with the same route parameters, the following approach can be used:

In this example record details is opened on the Details page by clicking on the List page or via an hyperlink of a button in an email message. On the other hand, the record is reloaded on refreshing page.

***list-component.html:***

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/detail/']" [queryParams]="{ id: row.Id }">{{ row.Title }}</a>
```

***details-component.ts:***

```
this.id = +this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get("id"); 
//"+" sign converts string to number as the url parameter is string
```

***routing-module.ts:***

```
{ path: 'user/detail', component: DetailComponent },
{ path: 'user/detail/:id', component: DetailComponent },
```

The page can be loaded via button and hyperlink also:

```
<a href="http://../detail?id=216" target="_blank" >Comment</a>
```